# Bookmark Limit?

Tags: xbox-one, elite-dangerous

I can't create any more bookmarks, and the game isn't saying why.

I like to bookmark systems I want to remember to stop at during exploration. Usually black holes, neutron stars, small nebulae, and such. I think I might have overdone it this time though.

I don't know how many bookmarks I currently have, but it's somewhere in between a lot and a metric butt-tonne.

Is there some sort of unstated bookmark limit I've hit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit on how many bookmarks you can have.

Many posts have mentioned it, but [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteOne/comments/4ruwxt/i_reached_bookmark_capacity_already/) is the first documented number I have seen.

> it turns out that the maximum is 128 bookmarks

Comment: 400 billions stars... yeah 128 bookmarks will suffice.